# Package hyperref with backref: highlight the targeted text in same document and link back to the "fork"

Tags: hyperref, backref

I am experimenting with package hyperref with backref option. I've spent hours poring over hyperref documentation, and related docs, but I am getting mired.

I want to hyperref to some specific text in the body of the document (an in-line 'target'), and be able to hyperlink that target text (aka, the anchor; which would be highlighted in some manner) *back to the original point of diversion* in the text. In other words: a backref ---- but one ***not*** related to citations, bibliography, section numbers or page numbers.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you share a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), please?

Answer (score 2):

As an anchor can be the target of more than one link, there is no well defined "go back" target. So typically to "go back" you should use suitable tools of your PDF viewer (e.g. alt+arrow left in adobe reader).

If you have an 1-1 relation you can simply use two targets and links:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\hypertarget{back1}{}\hyperlink{back2}{Go back 1}
\newpage

\hypertarget{back2}{}\hyperlink{back1}{Go back 2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ha! I didn't know there was the PDF viewer tool for "go back" ! Thanks. And the other suggestion also works, but of course means more keystrokes. From the lack of any additional Answers, I assume that the backref established by citation-bibliography and by todo lists  cannot be turned on globally for other links.

Comment: You can program all sort of things, but your concept of backref is simply wrong: backref isn't a back-and-forth relation. A citation jumps to the begin of the reference, not to some specific backref value and a backref often only jumps to a *page*, not to a specific citation.

Comment: Ulrike: for clarifying the facts about a 'backref'. I will look again at the behaviour of the back-links.